# How to add extra spaces between rows in tabular environment?

Tags: math-mode, tables, spacing

I couldn't find any option that lets me expand the vertical space between rows in `tabular` environment. For example,

```
\begin{tabular}{c c}
    $f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\
    $-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0 
\end{tabular}
```

This looks awkward because of the powers of `x`. I wonder if there is an option to expand the vertical spaces between these rows?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You have at least three options here:

- Increasing the array stretch factor using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}` where `<factor>` is a numeric value:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    $f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\\hline
    $-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- Explicitly specifying the row skip using `\\[<len>]` where `<len>` is any length:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    $f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\[1cm] \hline
    $-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- Modifying the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `\extrarowheight` length using `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{<len>}`, where `<len>` is any length:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
  \begin{document}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    $f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\\hline
    $-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

In the above examples, the `\hline` was used to illustrate the effect of the different styles used. The choice depends on the specific usage/typesetting of the `tabular` within your document.

Finally, if the contents of your entire `tabular` is math, you could typeset it in an `array` environment:

```
\[
  \begin{array}{c c}
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer as well as many other alternative solutions ;)

Comment: How can I define the row skip (\\[1cm] in your example) with a multirow cell in my table? I would like to enlarge the space between all other cells which are spanned by the multirow, but defining the row skip just like you do it does not work.

Comment: @Rob: My suggestion would be to [ask a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with a clear demonstration of what you have and what you're after. You can then link to this post if you wish to provide some additional context.

Comment: Problem solved. \\\[1cm] was just not big enough to see any difference...

Comment: I had a table with many rows and I wanted to increase the space of only one row. The best solution for me in this case was to insert a vertical strut of the type \rule{0pt}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}, as mentioned here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65127/extra-vertical-space-after-hline-causes-a-gap-in-the-right-border-of-an-array

Comment: Careful if you are using matrices then `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` will stretch those too. To not effect the matrices, use `\\[1em]` to mark the row end within the table instead.

Comment: @user3613932: Yes, or provide some scoping via a group to limit the adjustment: `{`...`}` or `\bgroup`...`\egroup` or `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `booktabs`. Left is the output using `\midrule`, right the one with the `\hline` approach.

The left table is also improved by stating `\displaystyle` that uses less cramped superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CC}
f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
\midrule
-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\
\hline
$-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For multi-rows, you can try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
  $f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\[1cm]
  $-2e^{-x^{x^{x}}}$ & 0\\[1cm]
  $2x&\frac{x}{2}\\[1cm] 
.
.
.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is already covered by Werner's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually, the options any LaTeX beginner desired were born!

The new (May 2021) package `tabularray` has two options to set the space before and after the table rows: `abovesep` and `belowsep` of the parameter `rows`!

The same package have also analogous options for `columns`, together with many other useful parameters and column types.

The environment `tblr` works both on math and text mode.

Thanks to Jianrui Lyu (the author)!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
A pure \texttt{tblr} it's already OK
\[
\begin{tblr}{c c}
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0 
\end{tblr}
\]
but you can even set the space you need:
\[
\begin{tblr}{cells={c},rows = {abovesep=6pt,belowsep=8pt},}
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0 
\end{tblr}
\]
You can set the spacing also for one row only, indicating the number of the row with \verb|row{<number>}|:
\[
\begin{tblr}{cells={c},row{2}= {abovesep=4pt},}
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0
\end{tblr}
\] 

Here I add \verb|hline|s to better show the spacing:
\[
\begin{tblr}{c c}
    \hline
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    \hline
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\]
\[
\begin{tblr}{cells={c},rows = {abovesep=6pt,belowsep=8pt},}
    \hline
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    \hline
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\]
\[
\begin{tblr}{cells={c},row{2}= {abovesep=4pt},}
    \hline
    f^{(n)}(x) & f^{(n)}(0) \\
    \hline
    -2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}} & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have another option here - specifying row colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
%Light gray:
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

%Light cyan:
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\rowcolor{Gray}
$f^{(n)}(x)$ & $f^{(n)}(0)$ \\\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
$-2xe^{-x^{x^{x^2}}}$ & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Which gives you]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not really an answer to the question, but an interesting alternative.