# Extra vertical space after \hline causes a gap in the right border of an array

Tags: spacing, rules, arrays

I wanted to put a bit of space after an `\hline` in an `array`; the main suggestion floating round the Internet seems to be to use

```
\hline \\ [-1.5ex]
```

Unfortunately, this causes a gap in the line on the RHS of the `array`. A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|l|l|}%
\hline
& TEXT\\
\hline \\[-1.5ex]
&TEXT
\\\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you after? *Reducing* the gap between lines in your `array` or *increasing* it?

Comment: Increasing it. The -1.5ex is just because a full line is too much white space. The method is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696157/latex-hline-spacing .

Comment: For reference, if you want to add blank space (no borders) between two rows, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332528/increasing-the-space-between-two-rows). E.g. use `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Rather than fiddle with the properties of `\hline`, it's better -- in your case -- to provide typographic "struts": either a "top strut," which provides vertical spacing *above* the line on which it's placed, or a "bottom strut," which provides vertical spacing *below* the line on which it's placed. This idea is *not* original to me; it goes back (at least) to an article published by Claudio Beccari in *TeX and TUG News* in 1993. What's nifty about this approach is that one can place *both* a top strut and a bottom strut on a given line of an `array` or `tabular` environment.

The following MWE shows how this may be done. Note that I've switched from `array` to `tabular` in order to pare things down to the bare minimum; the vertical spacing issues related to `\hline` are the same for both environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
% Define typographic struts, as suggested by Claudio Beccari
%   in an article in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993.
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut

\begin{document}
With struts on the left, without struts on the right:

\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|}
\hline
TEXT\Tstrut\Bstrut\\ % top *and* bottom struts
\hline
TEXT\Tstrut\\        % top strut only
TEXT\Bstrut\\        % bottom strut only
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|}
\hline
TEXT\\ 
\hline
TEXT\\    
TEXT\\      
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've left some related comments on Werner's post...

Comment: @Mohan - You mention (in a comment left on Werner's answer) that your tabular environments are generated by some program (Stata, maybe?). If so, can't you set up the program to insert a `\Tstrut` instruction (rather than something like `\\[1ex]`, say) automatically after every `\hline`? Just a thought.

Comment: The arrays are generated by some Haskell code I've written. It's not inserting the strut commands that's tricky... it's the fact that the heights of entries might vary. Unless I've misunderstood something, if a particular entry is taller than a Tstrut, the strut will have no effect. Is that right?

Comment: @Mohan - It depends where the `\Tstrut` instruction is inserted. If it's inserted on the baseline, you're correct in assuming that it won't have an effect on stuff that's tall than Tstrut. Assuming that what's being typeset is some mathematical expression with superscripts, could you modify the Haskell code to insert a `\Tstrut` inside the superscript's argument?

Comment: thanks again for all the advice!  It's not in fact, a superscript; it's a representation used in linguistics, and you can have tables nested inside tables (to arbitrary depth). But when I was playing around I found that the padding I'm putting around tables can be made sufficient to distance nested tables from the hline, which is good enough. Thanks for all the help!

(Just in case you're interested, the result is at http://s14.postimage.org/5cy6abt7j/derivation_images_80.png .)

Comment: One more thing that I got bitten with is that the displayed table in the answer above has extra white space at the end when using strut compared to without. This can be resolved by changing `TEXT \Tstrut` to `TEXT\Tstrut` (i.e. taking away the space between text and `\Tstrut`).

Comment: @FanchenBao - Many thanks for noticing and pointing the issue caused by the space I had left before `\Tstrut` and `\Bstrut` in the first `tabular` environment. I've gone ahead and updated the MWE -- both the code and the associated screenshot.

Answer (score 14):

On a case-by-case basis you can insert a vertical strut (zero-width, vertical rule/object) to push the row contents away from others. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{1.5\normalbaselineskip} & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

I've inserted a vertical strut of height `1.5\normalbaselineskip` which is `18pt` in the above example, any length exceeding the about 70% of the baseline skip would work. For more information on column and/row padding, see [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

Note that I've used [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to supply the `\text` command for setting text in math mode. Even though this is just a simple example and using `\mbox` would also suffice, `amsmath` also provides other functionality that is well worth using.

---

If you wish to insert a fixed amount (say) `<len>` between two rows, you can insert a blank row (with the appropriate number of column alignments `&` to provide correct vertical rule placement) and use a row skip of the form `\\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+<len>]`. This would jump "back" a length of `\normalbaselineskip` - the baseline distance between rows - and jump "forward" by `<len>` - the required gap. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}[t]{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \text{Normal} \\
    \hline
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array} \quad
  \begin{array}[t]{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \texttt{0pt} \\
    \hline
    & \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array} \quad
  \begin{array}[t]{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \texttt{2pt} \\
    \hline
    & \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+2pt]
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array} \quad
  \begin{array}[t]{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \texttt{1em} \\
    \hline
    & \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+1em]
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array} \quad
  \begin{array}[t]{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    & \texttt{3pc} \\
    \hline
    & \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+3pc]
    & \text{Text} \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is one difficulty with this approach, which is that I'm automatically generating my LaTeX code in a program. So I can't tune the height on a case-by-case basis. I will experiment with putting in a constant-height strut, but what I really want to do is put a fixed amount of space between the hline and whatever comes after it, regardless of the height of the latter. 

Maybe I can wrap whatever comes after the hline in some kind of vertical box, with a strut placed above it? It's a bit fiddly, but it would probably work...

Comment: @Mohan: I've updated my answer with a possibility that might work for you. Give some feedback if it doesn't.

Comment: "with the appropriate number of column alignments & to provide correct vertical rule placement" --- ah! That's what I was missing. Thank you very much.  (Output is now also satisfactory, though I used other means.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a (missing) ampersand, otherwise the last cell and its border are not created:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|l|l|}%
\hline
& TEXT\\
\hline
& % <<<< here
\\[-1.5ex]
&TEXT
\\\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```