# tables: spaces between rows for a single row (top and bottom)

Tags: tables

I have this silly question that might look like a duplicate, but I still cannot get it to work... I have the following table, and I just need more vertical spacing at the top and bottom of the 3rd row... Adding [3cm] after the end of the row would give me more space at the bottom of the row, but what about the space at the top? Many thanks!
MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \textbf{group a}
        & \textbf{group b}
        & \textbf{group c}
        & \textbf{group d}\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{classif1}
        & A
        & B
        & A
        & B\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{classif2}
        & A
        & B
        & B
        & A\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{IDs}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ALK, APC,\\CDH1, EGFR,\\GPC3, HNF1A,\\MPL, PHOX2B,\\RET, TSHR}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{AXIN1, BRCA2,\\BUB1B, CDKN2A,\\ERCC2, ERCC4,\\FANCC, FANCE,\\FH, HRAS,\\MLH1, MSH6,\\NF1, PMS2,\\PRKAR1A, RB1,\\SBDS, SDHAF2,\\SDHB, SDHD,\\SMAD4, SMARCB1,\\STK11, SUFU,\\TP53, TSC1,\\XPA, XPC}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ATM, BLM,\\BRCA1, BRIP1,\\CDC73, CDK4,\\CHEK2, CYLD,\\DDB2, DICER1,\\ERCC3, ERCC5,\\EXT1, EXT2,\\FANCA, FANCD2,\\FANCG, FLCN,\\MSH2, MUTYH,\\NF2, PALB2,\\PMS1, RECQL4,\\SDHC, SMARCE1,\\TSC2, VHL,\\WRN}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{BMPR1A, FANCF,\\KCNJ5, KIT,\\LMO1, MAX,\\MEN1, NBN,\\PRF1, PTCH1,\\PTEN, TERT,\\WT1}}\\[3cm]
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{Number}
        & 10
        & 28
        & 29
        & 13\\
    \cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a case for the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cellspace package: "It is well known that high or deep cells tend to touch the `\hlines` of a tab­u­lar. This pack­age pro­vides a mod­i­fier `S` act­ing on usual col­umn types so that to en­sure a min­i­mal dis­tance that can be con­trolled through two pa­ram­e­ters `\cellspace­to­plimit` and `\cellspace­bot­tom­limit`."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force some additional vertical whitespace at the top and bottom of the cell in question, you could insert "struts" -- objects that have some height (and possibly depth) but no width, and hence are invisible. For instance, the instruction

```
\rule{0pt}{3cm}
```

will insert a "top strut" of height `3cm`, and

```
\rule[-3cm]{0pt}{0pt}
```

will insert a "bottom strut" of depth `3cm`.

To apply this to the table at hand, the cell in the "group c" column could be set up as

```
\textit{\pbox{20cm}{\rule{0pt}{3cm}ATM, BLM,\\BRCA1, BRIP1,\\CDC73, CDK4,\\CHEK2, CYLD,
  \\DDB2, DICER1,\\ERCC3, ERCC5,\\EXT1, EXT2,\\FANCA, FANCD2,\\FANCG, FLCN,
  \\MSH2, MUTYH,\\NF2, PALB2,\\PMS1, RECQL4,\\SDHC, SMARCE1,\\TSC2, VHL,
  \\WRN \rule[-3cm]{0pt}{0pt}}
```

For more on using struts in tables and on choosing strut height/depth settings that are typographically more appropriate than the `3cm` example you gave, check out [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65130/5001) (shameless self-citation alert!).

Comment: Cool! I have been playing around and got the aesthetics that I want. Though I'm still working with \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} along with the struts, is it ok, or the don't play well together?

Comment: As far as I know, inserting struts in no way interferes with resetting the `\arraystretch` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A first solution using the cellspace package, that defines  the minimal distance between the text and the top or the bottom of the cell (\cellspacetoplimit & \cellspacebottomlimit):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pbox, cellspace}
\cellspacetoplimit = 6pt\cellspacebottomlimit =6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c|*{4}{Sc|}}
\cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & \textbf{Class 1}
    & \textbf{Class 2}
    & \textbf{Class 3}
    & \textbf{Class 4}\\
\hline
   Penetrance
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous\\
\hline
   Expression
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous
    & Ubiquitous
    & Tissue specific\\
\hline
   Genes
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ALK, APC,\\CDH1, EGFR,\\GPC3, HNF1A,\\MPL, PHOX2B,\\RET, TSHR}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{AXIN1, BRCA2,\\BUB1B, CDKN2A,\\ERCC2, ERCC4,\\FANCC, FANCE,\\FH, HRAS,\\MLH1, MSH6,\\NF1, PMS2,\\PRKAR1A, RB1,\\SBDS, SDHAF2,\\SDHB, SDHD,\\SMAD4, SMARCB1,\\STK11, SUFU,\\TP53, TSC1,\\XPA, XPC}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ATM, BLM,\\BRCA1, BRIP1,\\CDC73, CDK4,\\CHEK2, CYLD,\\DDB2, DICER1,\\ERCC3, ERCC5,\\EXT1, EXT2,\\FANCA, FANCD2,\\FANCG, FLCN,\\MSH2, MUTYH,\\NF2, PALB2,\\PMS1, RECQL4,\\SDHC, SMARCE1,\\TSC2, VHL,\\WRN}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{BMPR1A, FANCF,\\KCNJ5, KIT,\\LMO1, MAX,\\MEN1, NBN,\\PRF1, PTCH1,\\PTEN, TERT,\\WT1}}\\%
\hline
    Number
    & 10
    & 28
    & 29
    & 13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Another solution uses  the booktabs package and its \addlinespace command, but supposes no vertical lines (look better in the opinion of many):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pbox, array, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c*{4}{c}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
    %\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & \textbf{Class 1}
    & \textbf{Class 2}
    & \textbf{Class 3}
    & \textbf{Class 4}\\
\toprule
   Penetrance
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous\\
\midrule
   Expression
    & Tissue specific
    & Ubiquitous
    & Ubiquitous
    & Tissue specific\\
\midrule\addlinespace
   Genes
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ALK, APC,\\CDH1, EGFR,\\GPC3, HNF1A,\\MPL, PHOX2B,\\RET, TSHR}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{AXIN1, BRCA2,\\BUB1B, CDKN2A,\\ERCC2, ERCC4,\\FANCC, FANCE,\\FH, HRAS,\\MLH1, MSH6,\\NF1, PMS2,\\PRKAR1A, RB1,\\SBDS, SDHAF2,\\SDHB, SDHD,\\SMAD4, SMARCB1,\\STK11, SUFU,\\TP53, TSC1,\\XPA, XPC}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{ATM, BLM,\\BRCA1, BRIP1,\\CDC73, CDK4,\\CHEK2, CYLD,\\DDB2, DICER1,\\ERCC3, ERCC5,\\EXT1, EXT2,\\FANCA, FANCD2,\\FANCG, FLCN,\\MSH2, MUTYH,\\NF2, PALB2,\\PMS1, RECQL4,\\SDHC, SMARCE1,\\TSC2, VHL,\\WRN}}
    & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{BMPR1A, FANCF,\\KCNJ5, KIT,\\LMO1, MAX,\\MEN1, NBN,\\PRF1, PTCH1,\\PTEN, TERT,\\WT1}}\\%
\addlinespace\midrule
    Number
    & 10
    & 28
    & 29
    & 13\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `tabular`s special struts `\@arstrut` are inserted; they are normal struts, but multiplied with factor `\arraystretch`.

Because the `\pbox`es are so large, the automatically inserted struts do not have an effect. It would be better to add the strut at the first and last line of the lines in the `\pbox`. However, because of the large `\arraystretch`, the strut in the first line of `\pbox` should not have a depth and the strut in the last line should not have a height. This is achieved by the optional parameters of `\raisebox{0pt}` that allows the setting of the height and depth.

**Further remarks:**

- The use of `\arstrutDP`, the strut with depth and zero height, in the last line of `\pbox` avoids the magic space value in the optional argument of `\\[30cm]`.
- Macro `\pboxIDs` calls `\pbox` with `\itshape` for its contents and adds the "half struts" to the first and last line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\arstrutHT}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\@arstrut}%
}
\newcommand*{\arstrutDP}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][\depth]{\@arstrut}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcommand*{\pboxIDs}[1]{%
  \pbox{20cm}{%
    \itshape
    \arstrutHT
    \ignorespaces
    #1%
    \unskip
    \arstrutDP
  }%
}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \textbf{group a}   
        & \textbf{group b}   
        & \textbf{group c}   
        & \textbf{group d}\\ 
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{classif1}
        & A
        & B
        & A
        & B\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{classif2}
        & A
        & B
        & B
        & A\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{IDs}
        & \pboxIDs{ALK, APC,\\CDH1, EGFR,\\GPC3, HNF1A,\\MPL,
            PHOX2B,\\RET, TSHR}
        & \pboxIDs{AXIN1, BRCA2,\\BUB1B, CDKN2A,\\ERCC2,
            ERCC4,\\FANCC, FANCE,\\FH, HRAS,\\MLH1, MSH6,\\NF1,
            PMS2,\\PRKAR1A, RB1,\\SBDS, SDHAF2,\\SDHB, SDHD,\\SMAD4,
            SMARCB1,\\STK11, SUFU,\\TP53, TSC1,\\XPA, XPC}
        & \pboxIDs{ATM, BLM,\\BRCA1, BRIP1,\\CDC73, CDK4,\\CHEK2,
            CYLD,\\DDB2, DICER1,\\ERCC3, ERCC5,\\EXT1, EXT2,\\FANCA,
            FANCD2,\\FANCG, FLCN,\\MSH2, MUTYH,\\NF2, PALB2,\\PMS1, 
            RECQL4,\\SDHC, SMARCE1,\\TSC2, VHL,\\WRN}
        & \pboxIDs{BMPR1A, FANCF,\\KCNJ5, KIT,\\LMO1, MAX,\\MEN1,
            NBN,\\PRF1, PTCH1,\\PTEN, TERT,\\WT1}\\
    \cline{1-5}
        \textbf{Number}
        & 10
        & 28
        & 29
        & 13\\
    \cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]