# Kerning the table contents

Tags: tables

I have the MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Paramagnetic metal}&\textbf{Magnetic susceptibility}\\
\hline
Tungsten&$6.8~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Aluminium&$2.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Lithium&$1.4~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Magnesium&$1.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Sodium&$0.72~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Magnetic susceptibility  of some selected paramagnetic metals}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:
[image]

Now I would like to add some space between the `\hline` and `-5` and as well maintain the table look as such (without making it lengthier (I mean visibly)). When I see my document, it feels like, -5 is touching the line, which I don't want

Comment: Adding `\strut` to the cells might help.

Comment: Have you checked the discussion of inserting "struts" in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65130/5001?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `booktabs` too, avoiding rules as much as possible; but also `siunitx` for the second column, in order to fully align the numbers. Also the data are easier to input.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% load the golden pair for numeric tables
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=1.2E-1] }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Paramagnetic}} & {\textbf{Magnetic}}       \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{metal}}        & {\textbf{susceptibility}} \\
\midrule
Tungsten  & 6.8E-5\\
Aluminium & 2.2E-5\\
Lithium   & 1.4E-5\\
Magnesium & 1.2E-5\\
Sodium    & 0.72E-5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Magnetic susceptibility  of some selected paramagnetic metals}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Breaking the headers into two rows makes the table narrower and easier to read. The first column should be left aligned, rather than right aligned.

The value for `table-format` is easy to explain: your numbers have one digit for the integer part and at most two for the decimal part; then they have an exponential part, one digit with minus sign. Thus `1.2E-1`

The headers for the second column should be braced, in order for `siunitx` to center them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Package `array` provides `\extrarowheight`, which adds extra space to the height of the rows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Paramagnetic metal}&\textbf{Magnetic susceptibility}\\
\hline
Tungsten&$6.8~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Aluminium&$2.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Lithium&$1.4~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Magnesium&$1.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
Sodium&$0.72~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Magnetic susceptibility  of some selected paramagnetic metals}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And without the many ugly lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}% not really needed here
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\toprule
\textbf{Paramagnetic metal}&\textbf{Magnetic susceptibility}\\
\midrule
Tungsten&$6.8~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
Aluminium&$2.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
Lithium&$1.4~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
Magnesium&$1.2~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
Sodium&$0.72~\text{x}~10^{-5}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Magnetic susceptibility  of some selected paramagnetic metals}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result booktabs]

Comment: How do you get the light ping color in your background??? please tell me

Comment: @subhamsoni: I am putting the images inside a quotation: `> ![...][...]`. And I am generating the images with transparent background (ghostscript's `pngalpha` device or making it transparent using gimp).