# Removing a gap in vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables, line

How I can resolve this table problem. It cut a part of vertical line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{0.22\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}}
             & $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$\tabularnewline[0.2em]
            \hline \\
            $y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
            $y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
            $y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use `\\ ` after `\hline`

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `\\` after `\hline` as suggested by David Carlisle in the comment. If you want to add some vertical space after the 1st horizontal line, you can follow [this answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65130/219947). Combining these two, the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{0.22\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}}
             & $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$\tabularnewline[0.2em]
            \hline 
            $y=\log_{10}x$\Tstrut & $1$\Tstrut & $2$\Tstrut & $3$\Tstrut\tabularnewline[0.5em]
            $y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
            $y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `\hline\\` which could be

```
\hline &&& \\[-1.5ex]
```

(experiment the value). In general it's best to use `ex` units for vertical spacing.

I propose three realizations of the table, in decreasing order of ugliness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{
  w{c}{0.22\textwidth}|
  w{c}{0.20\textwidth}|
  w{c}{0.20\textwidth}|
  w{c}{0.20\textwidth}
}
& $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$ \\
\hline
&&&\\[-1.5ex]
$y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ \\[1ex]
$y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$ \\[1ex]
$y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc@{}}
\toprule
& $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$ \\
\midrule
$y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ \\
\addlinespace
$y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$ \\
\addlinespace
$y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{center}

\begin{center}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
Funzione & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Valore di $x$} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
& $10$ & $100$ & $1000$ \\
\midrule
$y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ \\
\addlinespace
$y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$ \\
\addlinespace
$y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Avoid `[H]`; if there is no caption, a `center` environment suffices. If there's a caption, let the environment float.

[image]

I left “y=”, but I consider it bad mathematical usage.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{0.22\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}}
     & $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$\tabularnewline[0.2em]\hline 
     & & &\tabularnewline[0.2em]
    $y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
    $y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
    $y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `\\` after `\hline`. If you want to add space after `\hline`, you can add `\noalign{\vskip1mm}`. This will break the vertical rule. However, if you use `{NiceTabular}` instead of `{tabular}`, the rules won't be broken (with `nicematrix`, the rules are drawn with PGF/Tikz after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\centering}m{0.22\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.20\textwidth}}
     & $x=10$ & $x=100$ & $x=1000$\tabularnewline[0.2em]
    \hline 
    \noalign{\vskip1mm}
    $y=\log_{10}x$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
    $y=x^2$ & $10^2$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$\tabularnewline[0.5em]
    $y=10^x$ & $10^{10}$ & $10^{100}$ & $10^{1000}$
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]