# Adding vertical space in multirow table

Tags: tables, multirow

How can I add some vertial space above and underneath the vector (and the line) with keeping the two entries in the second column vertically centered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{ $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $} & $0$ \\  & $0$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65127/extra-vertical-space-after-hline-causes-a-gap-in-the-right-border-of-an-array

Answer (score 2):

By use of `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = solid,  % draw the first and last \hline
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c, mode=math]}}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}   &   0   \\  
                &   0   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]