# What is the function of \noalign?

Tags: tex-core

The use of `\noalign` is quite common.

For example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109976/increasing-the-length-between-rows-in-a-table) `\noalign` is used with `\vskip{}`to control the height of a table cell.

---

**How** does `\noalign` work *in general*, and how does it work *with* `\vskip`?

**What is the logic** behind the use of `\noalign{\vskip}`?

Comment: I wouldn't say that `\noalign` is common, if you are talking LaTeX. Indeed it's a low level TeX command (a primitive, actually). *Cave canem* or *Hic sunt leones* apply.

Comment: @egreg it's more or less common, depending who is answering the question:-)

Comment: Have you studied the TeXbook or TeX by Topic?

Comment: I think it's a nice mnemonic name meant to be used inside **alignment** whose content **doesn't align** (**no** *align*).

Comment: Martin: No I haven't, but I'm afraid that an answer to a simple question from those huge manuals would require a lot of understanding beforehand. **I asked the question here also to provide an answer to others**. Before asked the question I tried to search an answer from Google (and here), and did not get any solutions. Also, after your comment, tried to search _Texbook_ from Google, and did find only a .tex -file, which refused to compile.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically `\noalign` (which is a TeX primitive and not a supported LaTeX command) has to come as the first thing in a table row and its argument is evaluated as vertical mode material that is placed *between* rather than *in* the table rows. So `\vspace` just inserts vertical space. (If the table had vertical rules from `|` they would be broken by this additional space.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok, so basically \noalign is a low-level Tex command. But what do you mean by saying that it is "no a supported LaTeX command"? So does `\noalign` mean, that the argument is placed above the next row you write?

Comment: Yes it comes above the next  (and it is often used internally for doing calculations which need to be done before `\multicolumn`) by not supported I mean, like all tex primitives it is not hidden in latex2e but it is not a documented latex command, latex tabular environments do not have eto support its use (although in practice they do) same is true if you use `\cr` instead of `\\ ` for example