# Question about \multicolumn in Tabularx

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I have a table with two columns like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}

test & test \\ 

\multicolumn{2}{l}{test} \\

\end{tabularx}
```

However the multicolumn line does not function good (too close to the first line). Besides I read that `\multicolumn` should not cross any X columns.

What is the solution?

Comment: If you're interested in stretching out the table vertically, you can use a number of methods. See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) and/or [How to add extra spaces between rows in `tabular` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26690/5764) If one of these address your question, let us know. Regarding the cross of `X`-columns: `\multicolumn` doesn't care about that.

Answer (score 2):

Please always post complete. documents not just fragments. the spacing you get here is unaffected by `tabularx` you would get the same spacing from `tabular` `p` columns. I a not sure why you say it is "too close" as it is teh standard row spacing that you would get without the `\multicolumn` However I insert an extra 20pt space in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}

test & test \\[20pt]

\multicolumn{2}{l}{test} \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```