# Vertical space distribution when arraystretch is increased

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment

When I increase the arraystretch for a table, the vertical space between the top of the text and the bottom of the text is not equally distributed.

**Why is that? And what can I do to make it equally distributed?**

The code-

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
This is a one row one column table.\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here's the space distribution-

[image: space_distribution]

Comment: Related: [How to add extra spaces between rows in `tabular` environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26690/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is well known. I don't know the exact reason, but I know two possible solutions:

- the `makecell` package defines a `\setcellgapes` command, which lets you define a height and a depth to add to the cells. These are added by the `\makegapedcells` command (does not work with `m` columns, as mentioned by @Zarko).
- the `cellspace` package defines a *minimal* vertical spacing between the contents  of a cell and its top or its bottom: `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`. They are applied to the cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{13.2ex}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{13.2ex}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{10}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
This is a one row one column table.\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\qquad
{\setcellgapes{13.2ex}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
This is a one row one column table.\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{Sc}
\hline
This is a one row one column table.\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should mentioned, that `\makegapedcells` doesn't work with `m` columns.

Comment: @Zarko: Didn't know that – I've never used it with columns, as far as I can remember. I've added this information (with credits!). Thanks!

Comment: How can I use cellspace vertical spacing in multirow tables? it does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: @NickG: I don't remember having a problem with multirow, so perhaps you should post a complete minimal code illustrating the problems you have, that we can experiment with, to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the asymmetry is that Latin letters typically have more height than depth, so the baseline of a text row is typically positioned such that 70% of the space is above the baseline and 30% below.

So you see the same thing if you use `\baselinestretch` to doublespace rows, the height and depth of a line is increased so typically the space above the top line is increased by more than the space below the last.

In tables the table rows are stacked one above the other with no spacing, and even spacing is achieved by adding a `\strut` a 0-width rule that as height and depth set to the normal baseline spacing. `\arraystretch` works by simply multiplying the size of the strut so since its height is more than its depth, the height of the strut gets more added space.

The `array` package adds an extra feature `\addtorowheight` which adds to the height of the strut, you could copy its internals to give a command to add to the depth, but actually if you use a multiplier to get the depth right you can always fix up the height by adding (subtracting). so

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{25}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
This is a one row one column table.\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```