# Vertical spacing in table

Tags: tables, math-mode, spacing

I am trying to create a table, but inside has some mathematical fractions which is too wide for the table.

Originally I used arraystretch 1.4, the vertical space is too tight. So I wanted to stretch wider.

[image]

When I used 2.4, the problem is that it is not vertically aligned anymore.

[image]

The problem might not seem apparent in this, so when I increase further to 4, it is even less vertically aligned.

[image]

Can someone help me understand and find the correct solution? Thanks in advance.

PS: Incidentally, I use LuaLaTeX as the default compiler.

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.4}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5\tabcolsep}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt} L{75mm} !{\vrule width 1.5pt} L{75mm} !{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
            \hline
            As $\displaystyle f\left(x\right) \rightarrow +\infty$, & $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{f\left(x\right)} \rightarrow$
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394792/2388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cellspace` ensures a minimal vertical padding of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). This works better with the `p`column type, for some reason:

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{#1}}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5\tabcolsep}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt} L{75mm} !{\vrule width 1.5pt} L{75mm} !{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
            \hline
            As $\displaystyle f\left(x\right) \rightarrow +\infty$, & then $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{f\left(x\right)} \rightarrow$
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @James If this answer helps you, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer. If you have already done so, flag this comment as no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

with macro `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` pacakege. after removing all unnecessary code from your *mwe* the code of *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{array,
            makecell}   % new
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{| L{75mm} |  L{75mm} |}
        \hline
        As $f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$, & then $\dfrac{1}{f(x)} \rightarrow$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*note*: this solution doesn't works with `m` columns type!