# Add real space between rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-spacing

I would like to add some space between the rows in a table, specifically to prevent the brackets in my matrices to touch, cf. this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
foo & bar & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & bar & baz\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many questions on TeX.SE asking how to add space between rows in a table, and it seems to me that the answers always suggest increasing the value of `\arraystretch`, see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment) among many.

But as far as I can tell, this doesn't actually add space *between* rows, it simply stretches the rows vertically. If something fills the vertical space of the rows, as my matrices do, the content of these rows still touches, cf. below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
foo & bar & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & bar & baz\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is, is there a way to truly add space *between* rows in a table (other than inserting empty rows, which adds too much space)?

Comment: Have you tried `\addlinespace` of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package?

Comment: @Mico Nope. Let me check the booktabs documentation and try ...

Comment: `\\ ` takes an optional argument which is an amount of space to insert at the row separation.

Comment: If you're not using the `mymatrix` environment in other contexts, you could modify the definition to add additional vertical spacing.

Comment: @DonHosek The `mymatrix` is mostly used outside of tables, so I'd rather leave that alone.

Comment: @Mico Care to add your suggestion as an answer, since that's the solution I went for?

Comment: @Sverre - ok, give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs `\addlinespace` of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package.

[image]

`\addlinespace` takes an optional argument, which indicates how much vertical whitespace should be inserted. If no argument is specified, the parameter `\defaultaddspace` is applied, which is set to `0.5em` by the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{\left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}\right]}}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for "\addlinespace" macro

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}
foo & bar & baz\\ 
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\ \addlinespace
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\ \addlinespace
foo & bar & baz
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have two options `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` (the names are inspired by the parameters `\cellspacetoplimit` and `cellspacebottomlimit` of `cellspace`) that you can set once for all and they will apply to all the environments `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=1pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=1pt}

\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*3{l}}
foo & bar & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & bar & baz\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Does this package also allow adding this extra space for selected tables? In my case, I don't need to add extra white space in tables that don't have matrices.

Comment: With the keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit`, `nicematrix` won't add space in all the `{NiceTabular}`. It will only add space in the cells which have a height or a depth greater than the standard height and depth of a row in `{tabular}`. That is to say, `\begin{tabular}{cc}A&B\\ C&D\end{tabular}` will have the same output as `\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}A&B\\C&D\end{NiceTabular}`. However, in `{NiceTabular}`, you can also add vertical space with the tools avaiable in `{tabular}`. You can write `\\[1mm}` or use `\addlinespace` of `booktabs`.

Answer (score 5):

Does this solve the problem

**No extra packages**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
foo & bar & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\[8pt]
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\[8pt]
foo & bar & baz\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**edit adding a strut predefined also works **

same result

[image]

```
\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}}
\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
    foo & bar & baz\\
    foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom}\mystrut & baz\\[8pt]
    foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom}\mystrut & baz\\[8pt]
    foo & bar & baz\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: That would work, yes. In the end, I went for `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to obtain what you want automatically with `cellspace`, which defines minimal vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed  with the letter `S`, or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or even any letter you please through the `column=`  loading time option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\newcommand*{\mymatrix}[1]{
 \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
 }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*3{Ol}}
foo & bar & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & \mymatrix{top\\bottom} & baz\\
foo & bar & baz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @projetmbc: Thank you for making the code readable. As often, I had forgotten to check…

Comment: Does this package also allow adding this extra space for selected tables? In my case, I don't need to add extra white space in tables that don't have matrices.

Comment: @Sverre: It doesn't adds extra space systematically  – it adds extra space if the actual spacing is less than the minimal values, so as to obtain these minimal values. That's the main difference with the `\makegapedcells` command from `makecell` or the `extrarowheight` length defined by `array`