# Placing 10 aligned tables in one page

Tags: tables, align

I have 2 different kinds of tables:

One has more rows and is shorter
[image: More rows]

And another with less rows but longer
[image: Longer]

I have 5 sets of each (total 10 tables).
Is there a way to place each set side by side? That is, `[shorter,longer]` and have a title per set (5 titles in total) in one page?

I'm currently generating the tables one at a time and it's taking a lot of pages (I'll just show 1 set):

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Title 1}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]ccS[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
\thead{Parameter} & {\thead{Actual\\ Value}} & \thead{Range} & {\thead{Parameter\\ Found}} \\
\midrule
$\alpha$ & 0.191 & (0.191, 0.191) & 0.191\\
$\beta$ & 0.05 & (0.05, 0.05) & 0.05\\
$\gamma$ & 0.0294 & (0.0294, 0.0294) & 0.0294\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Title 1}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]ccS[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
\thead{(S,I,D,R) Error NN} & & \thead{(S,I,D,R) Error Learnable Parameters} } \\
\midrule
(0.004, 0.025, 0.003, 0.003) & & (0,0,0,0) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It may be possible, depending on the actual page size, but it can't be done if each is enclosed in a separate `table` environment.  (That is a "float", and is always treated as a separate object.)  Try using just `tabular` without a blank line between two of them, and see if they fit within the width of the page.  If not, would they fit if they were rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise?  (You can insert captions later, using the `caption` package.)

Comment: So I removed the `table` parts from both and and blank line in between. Now I just have them one on top of each other, but not side by side. Is there a way to force size such that I can fit the 10 nevertheless?

Comment: Often, the suggestion is to pack each into a minipage, where you can specify the width (say, `.48\textwidth`), so that two would fit on a "line" with a minimum space between.  But the wider form may be too wide for that,  (You'd get "overfull hbox" messages, and maybe overprinting, but if properly specified, they'd appear next to each other.  That's why I suggested also considering landscape presentation.

Comment: **(i)** you have error in your code fragment, **(ii)** your table has defined more columns than are used (first table define 5, used 4; second table defined 5, used 2), **(iii)** page layout of your document is unknow.

Comment: @Zarko Where do you see the defined columns? Apologies, I'm still learning. How can I find the page layout?

Comment: For example at second table: `begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]ccS[table-format=1.4]}` is defined 5 columns: `l`, `S`,`c`,`c` and again `S`, you use only (the first) two. I suggest you to make yourself more familiar with writing of table by reading some introductory text about them, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: What about the captions? Should each table keep its individual caption or do you want a shared caption, probably with subcaptions, for each pair of tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to fit two such tables side by side, if you use suitable margins and a slightly redesigned second table. Here are two different suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} % only used in second example


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Title 1}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.4]ccS[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
\thead{Param.} & {\thead{Actual\\ Value}} & \thead{Range} & {\thead{Parameter\\ Found}} \\
\midrule
$\alpha$ & 0.191 & (0.191, 0.191) & 0.191\\
$\beta$ & 0.05 & (0.05, 0.05) & 0.05\\
$\gamma$ & 0.0294 & (0.0294, 0.0294) & 0.0294\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\toprule
& \thead{(S,I,D,R)}\\
\midrule
\thead[l]{Error NN} & (0.004, 0.025, 0.003, 0.003) \\
\thead[l]{Error Learnable\\ Parameters} & (0,0,0,0) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Title 1}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{subcaption left table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.4]ccS[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
\thead{Param.} & {\thead{Actual\\ Value}} & \thead{Range} & {\thead{Parameter\\ Found}} \\
\midrule
$\alpha$ & 0.191 & (0.191, 0.191) & 0.191\\
$\beta$ & 0.05 & (0.05, 0.05) & 0.05\\
$\gamma$ & 0.0294 & (0.0294, 0.0294) & 0.0294\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{subcaption right table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\toprule
& \thead{(S,I,D,R)}\\
\midrule
\thead[l]{Error NN} & (0.004, 0.025, 0.003, 0.003) \\
\thead[l]{Error Learnable\\ Parameters} & (0,0,0,0) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to align the tables though? Looks like the one of the left is lower than the one on the right. I tried to use invisible spacing but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "align"? The two tables are not equally tall, but both tables are top aligned with respect to each other.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong word, apologies. Is there a way to make them the same size? So they will start at the same spot (which they currently are), and end at the same spot (which the left table is lower currently)

Comment: I think the issue can be fixed with making the title longer on the right (I did it with ` \\ )`, but couldn't get it to work otherwise

Comment: Okay I solved it using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment)