# adjust row height of tabular

Tags: tables, height

I have the following table and try to adjust the row height so that the text is not as crowded as it currently is. Is there a method to do so?

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Variable Conceptualizations} \\
\hline
Variable Function & Variable & Operationalization \\ \hline
Dependent Variable & Z{i,t-1} & $\frac{X_{i,t-1}}{Y_{i,t-1}}$ \\
Independent Variable & Var1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
Moderator Variable & Var3 & $\frac{X_{i,t}}{Y_{i,t}}$ \\
Control Variable & Var4 & $ln(X)_{i,t}$ \\
 & X & $\frac{X_{i,t}} {X_{i,t}}$ \\
 & Var5 & $\frac{X_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}}$\\
 & Var6 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text \\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var7 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var8 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var9 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var10 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var11 & Text \\ \hline
 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{CAPTION 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's [math mode - How to add extra spaces between rows in tabular environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment) --

Answer (score 3):

Another possibilities is use of the `tabularray` package and accordingly set its parameters (in your case for example  `rowsep = 5pt`):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\sct{\SetCell{c, m, mode=text}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l Q[l] Q[c, $]},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},
              row{2} = {mode=text},
              row{3-Z} = {rowsep = 5pt}
             }
                    
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    Variable Conceptualizations
                        &           &                               \\
    \midrule[1pt]
Variable Function       & Variable  &   Operationalization          \\ 
    \midrule 
Dependent Variable      & Zi,t-1    & \frac{X_{i,t-1}}{Y_{i,t-1}}   \\
Independent Variable    & Var1      &\sct   {Text\\ Text2}          \\
                        & Var2      &\sct   {Text\\ Text2}          \\
Moderator Variable      & Var3      & \frac{X_{i,t}}{Y_{i,t}}       \\
Control Variable        & Var4      & \ln(X)_{i,t}                  \\
                        & X         & \frac{X_{i,t}} {X_{i,t}}      \\
                        & Var5      & \frac{X_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}}       \\
                        & Var6      &\sct   {Text\\ Text2}          \\
                        & Var7      &\sct   {Text\\ Text2}          \\
                        & Var8      & \frac{X}{Y}                   \\
                        & Var9      & \frac{X}{Y}                   \\
                        & Var10     & \frac{X}{Y}                   \\
                        & Var11     &\sct   {Text\\ Text2}          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{CAPTION 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If you maybe prefer to have in the second column math terms in `displaystyle`, then change column specification to:

```
colspec = {l Q[l] Q[c, $$]}
```

or

```
colspec = {l Q[l] Q[c, mode=dmath]}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the  `cellspace` package, which defines a minimal vertical spacing in all cells of a column with specifier prefixed with the letter S (or C if you load`siunitx`, or whichever letter you please with the package loading option `[column=some letter]`).
I also took the liberty to simplify your code, replacing the nested tabulars with the `\makecell` command, and improved the legibility of the resulting .pdf with the `\dfrac` command, in the place of `\frac`.
Finally, I replaced the `\hline`s commands with `\midrule`s from `booktabs`, as they have some vertical spacing above and below.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{llSl}
    \textbf{Variable Conceptualizations} \\
    \midrule
    Variable Function & Variable & Operationalization \\ \midrule
    Dependent Variable & Z{i,t-1} & $\dfrac{X_{i,t-1}}{Y_{i,t-1}}$ \\
    Independent Variable & Var1 & \makecell{Text\\ Text2} \\
     & Var2 & \makecell{Text\\ Text2} \\
    Moderator Variable & Var3 & $\dfrac{X_{i,t}}{Y_{i,t}}$ \\
    Control Variable & Var4 & $\ln(X)_{i,t}$ \\
     & X & $\dfrac{X_{i,t}} {X_{i,t}}$ \\
     & Var5 & $\dfrac{X_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}}$\\
     & Var6 & \makecell{Text \\ Text2} \\
     & Var7 & \makecell{Text\\ Text2} \\
     & Var8 & $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ \\
     & Var9 & $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ \\
     & Var10 & $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ \\
     & Var11 & Text \\ \midrule
     & & \\ \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{CAPTION 1}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, which is similar to the classical `{tabular}` has a key `cell-space-limits` to address that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lll@{}}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
\textbf{Variable Conceptualizations} \\
\toprule
Variable Function & Variable & Operationalization \\ 
\midrule
Dependent Variable & Z{i,t-1} & $\frac{X_{i,t-1}}{Y_{i,t-1}}$ \\
Independent Variable & Var1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
Moderator Variable & Var3 & $\frac{X_{i,t}}{Y_{i,t}}$ \\
Control Variable & Var4 & $ln(X)_{i,t}$ \\
 & X & $\frac{X_{i,t}} {X_{i,t}}$ \\
 & Var5 & $\frac{X_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}}$\\
 & Var6 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text \\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var7 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Text\\ Text2\end{tabular} \\
 & Var8 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var9 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var10 & $\frac{X}{Y}$ \\
 & Var11 & Text \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{CAPTION 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]